# How do you call a Vim built-in function?

Tags: vim

In section 4 of the Vim reference manual, it lists a number of builtin functions:

```
4. Builtin Functions                                    *functions*

See |function-list| for a list grouped by what the function is used for.

(Use CTRL-] on the function name to jump to the full explanation.)

USAGE                           RESULT  DESCRIPTION     ~

abs({expr})                     Float or Number  absolute value of {expr}
acos({expr})                    Float   arc cosine of {expr}
add({object}, {item})           List/Blob   append {item} to {object}
and({expr}, {expr})             Number  bitwise AND
append({lnum}, {text})          Number  append {text} below line {lnum}
```

How do I call these functions? How do I for example get the absolute value of a number?

Answer (score 2):

You can call a built-in function like so, with the call command, or in an expression:

```
let x = abs(-2)
" or, for functions where you're not interested in the return value:
:call clearmatches()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reference manual is borderline useless without the foundations provided by the user manual.

Functions are introduced in chapter 41 of the user manual:

```
:help usr_41.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note there is no visible difference between user functions and built-in functions from a usage point of view.

Functions that return nothing are meant to be called with `:call` -- note, that they will still always return 0.

The other functions return expressions. These expressions can be

- used to build more complex expressions

  - as they are passed around to other functions
  - as they concatenated, added, multiplied...
  - as they are used as index `getline('.')[col('.')-1]`
- passed to vim ex-commands that could be used to

  - `:echo` an expression
  - assign an expression into a variable with `:let`
  - `:execute` another vim ex-command, .e.g `:exe line('$')/2`